# Lazy getter doesn't work in classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter

```
class a {
    get b() {
        delete this.b;
        return this.b = 1;
    }
}

var c = {
    get b() {
        delete this.b;
        return this.b = 1;
    }
}

console.log(c.b); // works as expected
console.log((new a()).b); // throws error
```

The above code should work fine but the last line throws.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property b of # which has only a getter(…)

Clearly the getter is not being deleted in class whereas it works fine in object. I am on latest stable chrome.

[Lazy Getter MDN Entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters)

Comment: You don't have a constructor in `class a`

Comment: @Redu Constructor is optional in js classes.

Comment: I could not find a reference after a fair amount of googling, so I'm making this a comment instead of an answer -- but I am 95% certain that methods in classes end up being non-configurable, and hence, delete fails.  You can mimic that behavior in "regular" classes.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher So it's by design immutable. Cool. I can accept that if you add it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The getter of the class sits on the `.prototype` object, not on `this`, that's why your attempt to `delete` it fails (and, as Jeremy points out, it is not deletable).

You can however <s>simply</s> create an own property on the instance that shadows the getter:

```
class a {
    get b() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "b", { value: 1, writable: false, configurable: true })
        return this.b;
    }
}

var c = new a;
console.log(c.b); // 1
```

We have to use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) as a simple assignment would find the inherited property that has no setter and throws.

Comment: Oh.. shadowing a getter -- that idea never crossed my mind.  That's cool.

Comment: You are just creating the `b` property of `a` i don't think you need all that ceremony. Just do `get b() { return this.b } set b(v) {this.b = v}` and it's all fine.

Comment: @Redu: That's infinite recursion?

Comment: I just did `class aa {  get b() {return this.b;} set b(v) {this.b = v} }` and then `zz = new aa();` then `aa.b = 100;` then `aa.b;` returns `100` as expected.

Comment: @Redu: Try `zz.b = 100` and you'll get a *Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*

Comment: Yes sorry... well my bad but it comes back to answer... `zz.hasOwnProperty("b"); // false` `"b" in zz; // true` so `b is in the prototype chain. So the getter and setter may access `b` through `this.constructor.prototype.b`

Comment: @Redu: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @Bergi You are a genius!

Comment: Might be worth explaining why this will memoize the property  (or at least point out inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

By design, class properties are not deletable -- reference: https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties

Instance Field Initialization Process

The process for executing a field initializer happens at class instantiation time. The following describes the process for initializing each class field initializer (intended to run once for each field in the order they are declared):

- Let instance be the object being instantiated.
- Let fieldName be the name for the current field (as stored in the slot on the constructor function).
- Let fieldInitializerExpression be the thunked initializer expression for the current field (as stored in the slot on the constructor function).
- Let initializerResult be the result of evaluating fieldInitializerExpression with this equal to instance.
- **Let propertyDescriptor be PropertyDescriptor{[[Value]]: initializerResult, [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: false}.**
  Call instance.[[DefineOwnProperty]](fieldName, propertyDescriptor).

Comment: Nothing in this question is about the proposed ES class properties syntax.

Comment: That is incorrect, the spec [link](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation) and all major browsers they have configurable:true and enumerable:false. For properties on object literals the enumerable is true

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously this is about constructors. When you neglect the constructor the property you define with the getter gets created at the constructors prototype hence the correct way of doing the job probably should be like as follows;

```
class a {
    get b() {
        delete this.constructor.prototype.b;
        return this.constructor.prototype.b = 1;
    }
}
z = new a();
z.b; // 1
```

Comment: Referencing `this.constructor.prototype` is usually a bad idea when it comes to subclassing. Just explicitly reference `a.prototype` if that is what you mean.

Comment: In what environment are you executing this in? As Jeremy points out above, this should throw in ES6.