# Why do lazy getters work with prototypes but not with classes?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, setter, getter

Consider the following code:

```js
const defclass = prototype => {
    const constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
};

const Person = defclass({
    constructor: function Person(firstname, lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname  = lastname;
    },
    get fullname() {
        delete this.fullname; // doesn't delete on instances
        return this.fullname = this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    }
});

const john = new Person("John", "Doe");
const jane = new Person("Jane", "Doe");

console.log(john.fullname); // John Doe
console.log(jane.fullname); // Jane Doe
```

This works because the property assignment on `this` shadows the non-existent setter.

---

Now, consider the same code using ES6 classes:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(firstname, lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname  = lastname;
    }

    get fullname() {
        delete this.fullname; // doesn't delete on instances
        return this.fullname = this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    }
}

const john = new Person("John", "Doe");
const jane = new Person("Jane", "Doe");

console.log(john.fullname); // throws an error because there is no setter
console.log(jane.fullname);
```

The reason why it doesn't work is explained in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978698/783743). It's because we find the property in the prototype chain and it doesn't have a setter. So, why isn't the same error thrown when we use regular prototypes?

**Note:** You can delete the line with the `delete` keyword without affecting the behavior of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *do* get the same error with the first code:

```js
const defclass = prototype => {
    const constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
};

const Person = defclass({
    constructor: function Person(firstname, lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname  = lastname;
    },
    get fullname() {
        "use strict";
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return this.fullname = this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    }
});

const john = new Person("John", "Doe");
const jane = new Person("Jane", "Doe");

console.log(john.fullname); // John Doe
console.log(jane.fullname); // Jane Doe
```

It's just that `class` code is in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) by default.

In sloppy mode, the assignment doesn't work but is ignored and the right hand side value is `return`ed from the getter. Accessing `.fullname` again would run the getter again.

Comment: Makes sense. However, I do believe that this shouldn't be an error in strict mode.

Comment: @AaditMShah Why do you believe that?

Comment: Nevermind. Your edit clarified things. I understand why it's disallowed in strict mode now.